# On relativistic kinematics of particle accelerators

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, kinematics, scattering

While reading [these](http://www.matfis.uniroma3.it/Allegati/Dottorato/CORSI/Materiale/10013_300/Lecture%203%20-%20Cross%20Section%20Measurements.pdf) lectures I came across the following

[image]

Putting together the first two formulae one reads $M=E_{cm}$, or equivalently, the centre of mass is *always at rest*. But is it true? It might be true for colliders, but certainly not for fixed-target experiments.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Comment: Toni Baroncelli "Experimental High Energy Physics at Colliders", Winter 2017 ???

Comment: The author is him, I'm not sure about the title and the year. Anyway the overall topic is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *invariant* mass is equal to the total energy in the center-of-momentum reference frame. This does not mean that the center-of-momentum frame must coincide with the lab frame. Instead it means that it is possible in principle for the collision to produce a particle with mass $M$ which is at rest in the center-of-momentum frame. Particles less massive than $M$ can only be produced if there is some other particle to carry away the excess energy, and particles heavier than $M$ can only be produced virtually.

Comment: But aren't $p_1=(E_1, \vec{p}_1)$ and $p_2=(E_2, \vec{p}_2)$ calculated with respect to the lab frame?

Comment: You get the same invariant quantities no matter which frame you start in. That is the great thing about Lorentz invariance. I suggest you choose two frames for $p_1,p_2$, connect them by an appropriate boost, and work out the algebra to see how all of the transformation terms cancel out when you compute the invariant quantities.